# LXC, Ubuntu Container - Having problems with a package while installing libraries

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, lxc, lxc-docker

I tried installing libraries for a Unix benchmark to test my ubuntu LXC container when i get this return at the end.

Command:

```
ubuntu@BenchLXC2:~$ sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxext-dev perl perl-modules make git grc
```

Result (at the end):

```
Preparing to unpack .../patch_2.7.1-4ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking patch (2.7.1-4ubuntu2.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-dri2-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-dri2-dev_2.8-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-dri2-dev (2.8-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-gl-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-gl-dev_1.4.17-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-gl-dev (1.4.17-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-mesa-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dev_10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dev (10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running

```
ubuntu@BenchLXC2:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

But I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libroken18-heimdal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libroken18-heimdal
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
90 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 162 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot get security labeling handle: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This package */var/cache/apt/archives/libroken18-heimdal_1.6~git20131207+dfsg-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb* seems to be causing some issue but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Remove that package and try to reinstall it.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know the name of the package.